# How to enable utility control point in SQL Server 'Standard Edition (64-bit)'?

Tags: sql-server, 64-bit, ucp

I was trying to register a 64 bit machine under new Utility control point name, get the following 
"The SQL Server edition must support UCP creation. Validation failed. The specified instance of SQL Server cannot be used as a utility control point because the feature is not enabled in SQL Server 'Standard Edition (64-bit)'. For more information, see the Help topic for this operation."

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for asking about the UCP. The creation of the UCP is only available on Datacenter, Enterprise, Developer, or Evaluation SKUs. Check out for the basic requirements - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210548.aspx.
Cheers,
Bill